# Spring Security, Form Login, and Concurrent Sessions

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to restrict a user from signing more than once (forcing the previous session to expire).

I've checked the documentation on the subject [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#d0e3816). I've set this up very similar to the documentation, but users are not being restricted to one session at a time. I can log in multiple times (in different browsers) with the same user and have multiple concurrent sessions going.

Here are what I believe to be the relevant bits of my security setup. I'm using custom UserDetailsService, UserDetails, and AuthenticationFilter implementations.

```
    <http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <!-- Make sure everyone can access the login page -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.do*" filters="none" />

        [...]

        <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.do" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="sha" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="[...]">
        <beans:property name="userManager" ref="userManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFilter" class="[...]">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="eventPublisher">
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/security_check" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
                <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.do?login_error=true" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
            ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.do" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/login.do?login_error=true!" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
            ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

I've also registered `org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher` as a listener in my web.xml file.

As far as I can tell, I've configured this according to the documentation. I can't tell why this isn't working. Could it have something to do with the fact that I'm using a form-based login? Or my custom implementations mentioned above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. If you reimplement UserDetails, you must provide a hashCode() method for SessionRegistryImpl to use. This is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had similar problem but after reading this post I found note about `hashCode()` and `equals()` in [`User`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) class comment, which implicitly suggests overriding those two methods in your class.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered but there is a much simpler solution which doesn't require configuring specific filters. You can add to the http tag the following XML to configure your sessions:

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
  <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" />
</session-management>
```

The rest of the form based login configuration is also overly complicated. I wrote a post here http://codehustler.org/blog/spring-security-form-login-tutorial/ which shows how to configure the form-login properly.