# Property <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" /> doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I'd like to limit the number of sessions for users.

Here is an example configuration (taken [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html)) that I used:

```
<http>
  <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
  <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />

  <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.htm" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class=
   "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class=
 "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
  <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

I don't get any errors and can see the number of users in `SessionRegistry`. But `maximumSessions` value is `1`, and I can create 2 sessions for one user (I used different browsers for that).

The following property also didn't lead to any exceptions: `<beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />`. I also tried to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` for UserDetails implementation (as it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670991/spring-security-form-login-and-concurrent-sessions)).

Why do I have an ability to log in twice for one user with this `maximumSessions` value? Should I limit sessions number somehow else? Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I didn't correctly override equals method with `EqualsBuilder`. As it's shown [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html), I had `.appendSuper(super.equals(obj))` line before actually needed comparisons, so even the same user details were different. Without this line everything's fine and I can't log in twice.